# Sending a json response in node js without status

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to send a json response to a GET call from node js server.
I am creating a json as follows

```
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;


env.server.get('localhost:3000/details', function(req, res) {
                if (req.query.code) {
                    request.get({
                        url: 'http://www.example.com/net2/getDetails?code=' + req.query.code
                    }, function(err, result, body) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('error :' + err);
                            res.status(404).json({
                                infoMsg: "Error"
                            });
                        } else if (result.statusCode == 200) {
                            var resultBody = {};
                            parseString(body, function(e, parsedResult) {

                                resultBody["userName"] = parsedResult.userName;
                                resultBody["userDept"] = parsedResult.department;
                                resultBody["userCat"] = parsedResult.category;
                                res.send(resultBody);
                            });
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log('Request failed .');
                }
            });
```

I am expecting a result which needs to be in this format

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "dept": "dept1",
    "cat": "cat2"
}
```

But the response which I am getting is in this format

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "name": "test",
    "dept": "dept1",
    "cat": "cat2"
  }
}
```

How to create a response which is in the expected format ie without status and data being added, where am I going wrong.

Comment: Code please. **[mcve]**

Answer (score 1):

If you're requesting the `JSON` with `Ajax Request`, then the `status` field is a primordial part of the 'res' and can't be removed.

Comment: But you can access the **JSON** content directlty with 'response.data'

Comment: Okay, but provider whose service I am calling expects the details in response, I don't have the permissions to access  the details which I am creating and sending.